# moment.format returning 3 days off

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I have the following code in my Angular app:

```
ctrl.getDate = function() {
  console.log(ctrl.day.date); => 2017-12-06T05:00:00.000Z
  return moment(ctrl.day.date).format('MMMM do YYYY'); => December 3rd 
    2017
  };
```

What is going on here?  The date passed is clearly 2017-12-06 but for some reason the '.format' method is changing it to a day 3 days earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capitalisation matters:

```
return moment(ctrl.day.date).format('MMMM Do YYYY');
```

Changing `do` to `Do`

Comment: Yes that solved the problem.  Thank you.  I will accept the answer as soon as the sit allows me too.

Answer (score 1):

As Aleksey said capitalisation matters, with "do" you take the day of week and with "Do" you'll have the day of month.
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/